# Android listview not scrolling to first position

Tags: android, listview, android-selector

```
 **header1** | **header2** | **header3** |
==========================================

 - List item 1
 - List item 2
 - List item 3
 - List item 4
 - List item 5
```

I've layout similar as above. I've headers and for each header a list-view shows the data There are many data to load. List-view contains a image and 3 text-views.
For every list item I've got 2 buttons in different layout

At top I've heading. Below heading, at the left I've list in a linear layout and at the right I've buttons in another layout.
the buttons will be working for selected list items.

My problem is I need to use d-pad and there comes a sort of end-user bug.
There is no error shown on log cat or anywhere.But while scrolling list-view sometimes without reaching the first element of list-view,the selector jumps to header.
I couldn't figure out Why does it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the list-view was stopping to scroll up and down, I couldn't get the reason behind this, but I got my solution changing list view to grid-view containing single column. And I also got a new idea that  custom - adapter for list-view and grid-view containing single column can be exactly same.

Answer (score 1):

> Try to call it in post because sometime `listview is not yet created` while you `calling it's method`

```
  getListView().postDelayed(new Runnable() {          
        @Override
        public void run() {
            lst.setSelection(15);
        }
    },100L);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below line:

```
listview.setSelection(1);
```

Comment: it selects the first item in list-view. I'll need to reach the position from buttons to the list-item so it won't be working. But thank you for your support.